# Doctrine2: field cannot be null when saving entity - due to relationships?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called `PrintJob`, with a `ProductId` field (amongst others). When I create a new instance of this entity and set all of the fields, then use persist followed by flush, I get an error saying that ProductId cannot be null.

I did a `var_dump()` on the `$productId` variable and it comes out as 47. I also did a `var_dump()` on `getProductId()` on the new entity (before persist/flush) and the value is still 47.

I think the problem lies with the relationship between the `PrintJob` entity and the `Product` entity. Here's the relationship from the `PrintJob` entity:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Product")
 * @JoinColumn(name="ProductId", referencedColumnName="ProductId")
 */
private $product;
```

I read somewhere that in the constructor, you need to set the relationship to an empty collection when you're creating new entities (rather than loading existing ones). Here is what I tried doing:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->product = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

However, I get an error:

> A new entity was found through a relationship that was not configured to cascade persist operations: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@000000002cb4568d00000000e92b0fce. Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship.

Any help would be much appreciated. The only alternative I've found is to not use relationships :(

I'm using Doctrine 2.0.7.

**Additional info:**

I'm not creating a new Product entity; the new PrintJob is being linked via the ProductId.

Here's how I am creating the entity - there are a lot of other fields that I can include in the code if it's useful, but I imagine they won't be as the issue is only occurring with ProductId...

```
    // convert this quote to a print job
    $printJob = new \Dpp\Model\PrintJob;
    $printJob->setProductId($productId);
    // ... other fields ...
    \Dpp\System\Core::getEm()->persist($printJob);
    \Dpp\System\Core::getEm()->flush();
```

\Dpp\System\Core::getEm() returns the EntityManager.

The mapping part from PrintJob to Product:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Product", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="ProductId", referencedColumnName="ProductId")
 */
private $product;
```

There is no equivalent mapping from Product to PrintJob.

Product entity - columns only:

```
namespace Dpp\Model;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="Brd_Products")
 */
class Product
{
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer", name="ProductId")
 * @GeneratedValue
 */
private $productId;
```

}

**Additional info #2:**

@JohnM2 pointed out that my associations are not set up correctly. So, here's what I now have.

\Dpp\Model\PrintJob

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Product", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="ProductId", referencedColumnName="ProductId")
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @return \Dpp\Model\Product
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->product;
}

/**
 * @param \Dpp\Model\Product $product
 * @return void
 */
public function setProduct($product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}
```

\Dpp\Model\Product

```
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer", name="ProductId")
 * @GeneratedValue
 */
private $productId;

public function getProductId()
{
    return $this->productId;
}
```

The code that saves the new entity:

```
$productEntity = \Dpp\Query\Product::getById($productId);
$printJob = new \Dpp\Model\PrintJob;
$printJob->setProduct($productEntity);
\Dpp\System\Core::getEm()->persist($printJob);
\Dpp\System\Core::getEm()->flush();
```

The first line returns an instance of \Dpp\Model\Product. I checked that $productId is set and that $productEntity is populated correctly.

Unfortunately, I now get an error on the "persist" line:

```
Property productId does not exist
```

I have a relationship from PrintJob pointing to Product. Do I need one in the opposite direction?

Nearly there though, I hope!

**Edit**

Never mind, found this last one myself. I needed to set the join column name to productId not ProductId. Fixed. Thank you all :)

Comment: "I get an error saying that ProductId cannot be null" Where do you get that error? If you don't, then cascade={"persist"} suggested by @jere is your answer.

Comment: That error occurs after creating the entity, setting the field values, then using persist followed by flush. The error occurs when I do flush. The entity is not saved.

Comment: It would help if you EDIT your question and show the code which create the entity, sets the field values and flushes. And also show Product entity definition (only fields, without methods).

Comment: are you creating a new instance of both entities? meaning, are you creating a new `PrintJob`, then a new `Product`, and setting that `Product` to the newly created `PrintJob`? maybe you can post the mapping of both entities and the code you are using to create the entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand now, you have `PrintJob::$product` field and also `PrintJob::$productId` field.
And you are trying to establish a connection between `PrintJob` and `Product` using explicit `productId` "foreign key" field of the `PrintJob` entity.

But it's not how ORM works. You don't need `PrintJob::$productId`, Doctrine will create appropriate foreign column from `PrintJob::$product` field (that what's @JoinColumn annotation says: `@JoinColumn(name="ProductId", referencedColumnName="ProductId")`). So instead you should establish an association between PrintJob and Product by assigning `Product` entity (loaded by EntityManager) to `PrintJob::$product` field by `PrintJob->setProduct($product)`.

Comment: Thank you - that explains a lot! So now when I save the entity, I'm using setProduct and not setProductId, and when I try to persist the entity I get an error: "Property productId does not exist". I'll update the original info with the revised code...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `cascade={"persist"}` to the `@OneToOne` annotation of `$product`, like so:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Product", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="ProductId", referencedColumnName="ProductId")
 */
private $product;
```

By default Doctrine doesn't implicitly persists associations to other entities, have a look at [this](http://www.krueckeberg.org/notes/d2.html#cascade-persist)

Also remove this line `$this->product = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();`
, it doesn't make sense to initialize something that is not a collection as a collection.

Hope it helps

Comment: Doctrine's docs on this topic http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#persistence-by-reachability-cascade-persist The important thing to remember is: "This concept is called Persistence by Reachability: New entities that are found on already managed entities are automatically persisted as long as the association is defined as cascade persist."

Comment: Thanks, I've made the necessary changes however I still get the "ProductId cannot be null" error when trying to flush to save the new entity. I'm using Doctrine 2.0.7 - will add this to the question. Do I need to add a relationship in the other direction, i.e. from Product to PrintJob?